# Looping through table rows and collecting data

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pandas, loops

I have the following data:

```
Node Case         dx         dy         dz
 1   A1   338.5E-9        0.0   163.6E-9
 1   A2        0.0        0.0        0.0
 1   A3  -133.4E-9  -268.4E-9  -22.36E-6
 5   A1   192.6E-9        0.0  -22.47E-9
 5   A2        0.0        0.0        0.0
 5   A3   231.5E-9  -268.4E-9  -35.82E-6
```

I would like to iteratively loop through each row of data and print out 'dx' 'dy' and 'dz' into a list  or (preferably) on a new table - see below. I would like the code to loop through each row until the column 'Node' becomes a different number (i.e. goes from 1 to 5).

So I would preferably like the first row of data on a new table to look like this:

```
        dx1        dy1        dz1       dx2        dy2       dz2         dx3        dy3        dz3   
   338.5E-9        0.0   163.6E-9       0.0        0.0        0.0   -133.4E-9  -268.4E-9  -22.36E-6
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome, is the index important? If you could drop the index then you could `df.set_index('[Node', 'Case]).unstack()`, which gets you pretty close without looping

Comment: or you could `df.pivot(index='Node', columns='Case', values=['dx', 'dy', 'dz'])`

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when I do this method I lose the ascending number order from the 'Node' column on the left. Is there a further step I can take to reorder the values? Also, would these methods work for more cases i.e. A1, A2, A3 and A4 etc?

Comment: And yes sorry the index is important - both of your methods give the following first line: [338.5E-9, 0.0, -133.4E-9, 0.0, 0.0, -268.4E-9, 163.6E-9, 0.0, -22.36E-6] which is not what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_out = (df.set_index(['Node', df.groupby('Node').cumcount()])[['dx', 'dy', 'dz']]
            .unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Output:

```
               dx0  dy0           dz0  dx1  dy1  dz1           dx2           dy2       dz2
Node                                                                                      
1     3.385000e-07  0.0  1.636000e-07  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.334000e-07 -2.684000e-07 -0.000022
5     1.926000e-07  0.0 -2.247000e-08  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.315000e-07 -2.684000e-07 -0.00003
```

Adding + 1 to cumcount:

```
df_out = (df.set_index(['Node', df.groupby('Node').cumcount() + 1])[['dx', 'dy', 'dz']]
            .unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Output:

```
               dx1  dy1           dz1  dx2  dy2  dz2           dx3           dy3       dz3
Node                                                                                      
1     3.385000e-07  0.0  1.636000e-07  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.334000e-07 -2.684000e-07 -0.000022
5     1.926000e-07  0.0 -2.247000e-08  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.315000e-07 -2.684000e-07 -0.000036
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there perhaps a way to begin the column headers as dx1, dy1 etc instead of dx0, dy0?

Comment: @MB1903 Sure, just add a + 1 after cumcount().  See update.

Comment: @MB1903 if this solution helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston - sorry just one more thing before I accept the solution, the Node numbering on the left is not in ascending order. Any way around this?

Comment: I have tried using df_out.sort_values(by=['Node'],axis=1, inplace=True) but it has not worked

Comment: The data is displaying in a strange order - 1, 100, 101, 102 etc. And (for example) further down it goes: 129, 13, 130, 131 etc.

Comment: Your Node is a dtype is 'object' or string.  You can change the dtype of Node to int. in your original dataframe or try `df_out.index = df_out.index.astype(int)`

Comment: @MB1903 Actually you need axis=0,  `df_out.sort_values(by=['Node'],axis=1, inplace=True)` is sorting columns axis=0 or leaving axis parameter out all together will sort rows.  if this doesn't work, then you dtype of your index is a string.